# format nested object to table on thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i build crm system,

i had object hes name users he hold also the data from details table (one to many realation)

lets says i had nested object name user and he had more than 1 object of details

i want to get this in the end in thymeleaf table
name  | entry date

david | 5/6/22

david | 1/7/22

but i got

name | entry date

david | 5/6/22 , 1/7/22

this is table code on thymeleaf:

```
<table class="table w-75 table-striped table-dark table-hover">
 <thead>
        <tr>
              <th scope="col" class="text-center">First name</th>
              <th scope="col" class="text-center">Entry Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="users : ${ParkingUsers}">
                <td class="text-center" th:text="${users.firstName}" />
                <td class="text-center" th:each="date, i: ${users.parkingDetails}" 
                th:text="${(i.index > 0 ? '' : '') + date.entryDate}" />    
                </tr>       
        </tbody>        
    </table>
```

how can i fix that?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for using the Thymeleaf [`th:block`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag) tag.

You can place the outer loop (for users) in this tag, and then place the inner loop (for parking details) in the `<tr>` tag.

Example:

Assume we have two classes:

```java
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private List<ParkingDetail> parkingDetails;

    // getters and setters

}
```

And:

```java
public class ParkingDetail {

    private LocalDate entryDate;

    // getters and setters
    
}
```

And assume we have a list of users: `List<User>`.

We can use the following in our Thymeleaf template:

```html
<table class="table w-75 table-striped table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Entry Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <th:block th:each="user : ${users}">
        <tr th:each="parkingDetail : ${user.parkingDetails}">
            <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
            <td th:text="${parkingDetail.entryDate}"></td>    
        </tr>   
    </th:block>
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Entry Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            
        <tr>
            <td>david</td>
            <td>2022-06-05</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>david</td>
            <td>2022-07-01</td>    
        </tr>   
            
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

The `th:block` tag allowed Thymeleaf to iterate over the list of users, but it did not cause any HTML to be generated. The Thymeleaf `${user}` variable created in the `th:block` tag can be referenced in all the child tags inside the `th:block`.

---

There are various other examples of how `th:block` can be used, in other questions on this site - so if this does not meet your needs, you can research those other questions.